# cefsharp object dispose after form close

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

cefsharp initialized in main form named "browser" and added to panel

```
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
```

now when button click , a new form "popup" with passed "browser" Showed:

```
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = panel1.Controls[2] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        popup ov = new popup(browser);
        ov.ShowDialog();
```

now browser object will remove in main form and passed to new form and when new form close and return to main form , `panel1` has no any `ChromiumWebBrowser` object and is null !

why `browser` object remove in main form when passed to new form, and why new form close passed object will disposed !?

Comment: I've added the `WinForms` tag as the behaviours you are seeing are related to the framework. You add a control to a new parent, it's removed from the old parent. It cannot be in two places at once. When the `Form` is closed, the handle is destroyed, this will subsequently destroy the handles of all children, including the browser.  You can parent the browser to a temp parent by enabling https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/116/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L251